# Determine libc version used to create static library

Tags: glibc

I am seeing symbol referencing errors with the static libraries I am using (available with OpenSPARC processor). I have glibc 2.15 on my system. How do I determine the version of glibc used to create the libraries so I can update my system accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

Static libraries do not convey the GLIBC version (unless this was added specifically to a internal variable or data during compilation time).

If you know what you are looking for, you might infer the GLIBC version based on the symbols that the library requires. Using nm you can get a list of those symbols:

```
nm -g staticlib.a
```